# Lisp web tales: How to fix the blogdemo example (Chapter 4)?

Tags: common-lisp

I came across Pavel's [tutorial](https://github.com/pvlpenev/lispwebtales) about writing a web app using CL and [RESTAS](https://github.com/archimag/restas) as a frame work. While simple `Hello, World!` examples work. I am not able to get the blog example from chapter 4 running.

Using `(restas:debug-mode-on)` I end up with the following backtrace:

```
invalid number of arguments: 0
  [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "hunchentoot-worker-127.0.0.1:59876" RUNNING {1009975FD3}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (BLOGDEMO::HTML-FRAME) [tl,external]
  1: (RESTAS::ROUTE-RENDER-METHOD #<RESTAS:ROUTE {100A16FE53}>)
  2: ((:METHOD RESTAS:PROCESS-ROUTE (RESTAS:ROUTE T)) #<RESTAS:ROUTE {100A16FE53}> NIL) [fast-method]
  3: ((FLET CALL-NEXT-METHOD :IN "C:/Users/martin_b/portacle/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/restas-20170124-git/src/route.lisp"))
  4: ((:METHOD RESTAS:PROCESS-ROUTE :AROUND (ROUTES:BASE-ROUTE T)) #<RESTAS:ROUTE {100A16FE53}> NIL) [fast-method]
  5: (RESTAS::RESTAS-DISPATCH-REQUEST #<RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR (host *, port 8080)> #<RESTAS::RESTAS-REQUEST {1003E5B383}>)
  6: ((:METHOD HUNCHENTOOT:ACCEPTOR-DISPATCH-REQUEST (RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR T)) #<RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR (host *, port 8080)> #<RESTAS::RESTAS-REQUEST {1003E5B383}>) [fast-method]
  7: ((:METHOD HUNCHENTOOT:HANDLE-REQUEST (HUNCHENTOOT:ACCEPTOR HUNCHENTOOT:REQUEST)) #<RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR (host *, port 8080)> #<RESTAS::RESTAS-REQUEST {1003E5B383}>) [fast-method]
  8: ((:METHOD HUNCHENTOOT:PROCESS-REQUEST (T)) #<RESTAS::RESTAS-REQUEST {1003E5B383}>) [fast-method]
  9: ((FLET CALL-NEXT-METHOD :IN "C:/Users/martin_b/portacle/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/restas-20170124-git/src/hunchentoot.lisp"))
 10: ((:METHOD HUNCHENTOOT:PROCESS-REQUEST :AROUND (RESTAS::RESTAS-REQUEST)) #<RESTAS::RESTAS-REQUEST {1003E5B383}>) [fast-method]
 11: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN HUNCHENTOOT:PROCESS-CONNECTION))
 12: (HUNCHENTOOT::DO-WITH-ACCEPTOR-REQUEST-COUNT-INCREMENTED #<RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR (host *, port 8080)> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN HUNCHENTOOT:PROCESS-CONNECTION) {1003C3439B}>)
 13: ((:METHOD HUNCHENTOOT:PROCESS-CONNECTION (HUNCHENTOOT:ACCEPTOR T)) #<RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR (host *, port 8080)> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {1009971333}>) [fast-method]
 14: ((FLET CALL-NEXT-METHOD :IN "C:/Users/martin_b/portacle/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/hunchentoot-1.2.35/acceptor.lisp"))
 15: ((:METHOD HUNCHENTOOT:PROCESS-CONNECTION :AROUND (HUNCHENTOOT:ACCEPTOR T)) #<RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR (host *, port 8080)> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {1009971333}>) [fast-method]
 16: ((FLET HUNCHENTOOT::PROCESS-CONNECTION% :IN HUNCHENTOOT::HANDLE-INCOMING-CONNECTION%) #<RESTAS:RESTAS-ACCEPTOR (host *, port 8080)> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {1009971333}>)
 17: ((:METHOD HUNCHENTOOT::HANDLE-INCOMING-CONNECTION% (HUNCHENTOOT:ONE-THREAD-PER-CONNECTION-TASKMASTER T)) #<HUNCHENTOOT:ONE-THREAD-PER-CONNECTION-TASKMASTER {10081F24C3}> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {1009..
 18: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN HUNCHENTOOT:CREATE-REQUEST-HANDLER-THREAD))
 19: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN BORDEAUX-THREADS::BINDING-DEFAULT-SPECIALS))
 20: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-1169 :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 21: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 22: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-359 :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX))
 23: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE) {6DAFB4B}> #<SB-THREAD:MUTEX "thread result lock" owner: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "..
 24: (SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "hunchentoot-worker-127.0.0.1:59876" RUNNING {1009975FD3}> NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN BORDEAUX-THREADS::BINDING-DEFAULT-SPECIALS) {..
 25: ("foreign function: #x42BEFC")
 26: ("foreign function: #x4038C1")
 27: ("foreign function: #x447080")
```

Obviously, there is a problem between the number of arguments the function `html-frame` is expecting and the number it is called using `render-method`. I checked the source and the RESTAS docs (which seem to be slightly out-dated) but could not understand what to change.

Is someone using RESTAS? Are there other up-to-date real life examples available one could study to learn? My impressions [from Cliki](http://www.cliki.net/web%20framework) was that there are several web-frameworks around but I found it hard to see which are actually used and maintained.

Comment: The same author has nethil if you want to use clack. Otherwise if you are starting out with Lisp I'd recommend to stick to hunchentoot and ruricolist/spinneret for html-templates

Comment: What is nethil? Is there more by the same author but using the Clack framework?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing back his:

```lisp
(defun start-blogdemo (&optional (port 8080))
  (start '#:blogdemo :port port :render-method 'html-frame))
```

To:

```lisp
(defun start-blogdemo (&optional (port 8080))
  (start '#:blogdemo :port port))
```

in `util.lisp`.

Then you need to make each of your routes in `blogdemo.lisp` read not like:

```lisp
(define-route home ("")
  (list :title "Blogdemo"
        :body (mapcar #'render-post *posts*)))
```

But instead like:

```lisp
(define-route home ("")
  (html-frame
    (list :title "Blogdemo"
          :body (mapcar #'render-post *posts*))))
```

The origin of this solution is that I didn't entirely understand the correctness of abstraction he was making (and wrangled quite a bit about on p37, which he also discusses [here](https://github.com/archimag/restas/issues/19)) so I reversed that and it worked.

---

Note also that the route `add` should look as below (the form with `:requirement` needs to come before html-frame, the latter being the last form hence the return value).

```lisp
(define-route add ("add")
  (:requirement #'logged-on-p)
  (html-frame
    (list :title "Add a blog post"
          :body (add-post-form))))
```

Likewise, the `:sift-variables`  forms should also come first in `author` & `post` routes, just like `:requirement`. Then the whole app should work for you.